# Property of fundamental matrix when $A(t)$ is antisymmetric

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\phi(t)$ be a fundamental matrix of a system of $n$ homogeneous linear ordinary differential equations $$x'=A(t)x.$$ I'd like to prove that if $A(t)$ is antisymmetric for all $t$, that is $[A(t)]^T=-A(t)$, then $$[\phi(t)]^T\phi(t)=C,$$ where $C$ is some constant matrix. I'm sorry, but I really couldn't make any good progress with it. If someone could give me a hint, I'd be grateful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try taking the derivative of $\phi(t)^T \phi(t)$ and use antisymmetry of $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact, $[\phi(t)^T\phi(t)]'=0$.

Comment: Exactly ! The result b.t.w. also holds if $x$ is a matrix (not sure if you included this possibility when posing the problem).

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is antisymmetric, then $e^A$ is orthogonal. And so is $e^{\int A(t)\,dt}$